# New Raspberry Pi SPI Interface Question

Tags: gpio, hardware, spi

I was looking at the new Raspberry Pi. I wanted to know if the SPI Interface will be able to sample at a higher sampling rate.
Does anyone have any information on this?

According to this page, the current Pi (B+) can sample at roughly 100 ksps:
[How to access SPI on Raspberry Pi B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28717/how-to-access-spi-on-raspberry-pi-b)

Does anyone know if the new Pi will be able to go above that sampling frequency, or does it stay the same (with only the core CPU speed increasing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPI peripherals are unchanged.

I suppose the transaction rate will have increased in line with the CPU but have not done any tests.